# Radio buttons is not saving the value correctly in DB MVC4?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi  i have  2 fields each field contain two radio buttons.  when i select the radio button and trying to save the value of Radio button in Db but it always save the value is zero. its not working correctly.

[My View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23VEL.jpg)

This is my fields **PaymentReceived** and **PaymentType**. Here i wrote j query code . if i select the  **POVisit** as **Payment** the **PaymentReceived** Radio button will appear and If i  select the **PaymentReceived** as **Yes** it  will show the **PaymentType** radio button Field and If i select Cash in PaymentType it will show the respective field otherwise all to be in hide mode.

My View Code

```
<div id ="PaymentReceived">
<div class="col-sm-4">
<div class="form-group">
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PaymentReceived, new { @class = "control-label" })
 @Html.RadioButton("PaymentReceived", 1) Yes
 @Html.RadioButton("PaymentReceived", 0) No
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
  <div id ="PaymentType">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="form-group">
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PaymentType, new { @class = "control-label" })
 @Html.RadioButton("PaymentType", 1) Cash
 @Html.RadioButton("PaymentType", 0) Cheque
 </div>
 </div>
  </div>
```

**My Controller code**

```
  if (visitorviewmodel.PaymentReceived == true)
  visitorviewmodel .PaymentReceived = true;
  else
  visitorviewmodel.PaymentReceived = false;

  if (visitorviewmodel.PaymentType == true)
  visitorviewmodel.PaymentType = true;
  else
  visitorviewmodel.PaymentType = false;

  var VisitorsViewObj = new VisitorsForm()
 {

 PaymentReceived = Convert.ToBoolean(visitorviewmodel.PaymentReceived),
 PaymentType= Convert.ToBoolean(visitorviewmodel.PaymentType),
 };
```

if i select Yes in Payment received  It will show the value as False in
**if (visitorviewmodel.PaymentReceived == true)**    if i select No  in PaymentReceived it will show the value as  false in if statement same as like for Payment type what ever i select the value in radio button it always show the value as false. now what i want is i want to save the value as per selected in radio button . that is if i select yes means it will save the value as 1 in DB if i select the value as no it have to save the value as 0 in DB. please any one help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Hard to understand what your doing here. Your use of `if (visitorviewmodel.PaymentReceived == true)` suggests these are `bool` properties so you cannot use values of `1` and `0` in your radio  buttons - its needs to be `@Html.RadioButton("PaymentReceived", true) Yes` (and another one for `false`)

Comment: ok lets i have a try

Comment: And using a `boolean` property for `PaymentType` makes even less sense - if the values are `Cash` and `Cheque`, then you property should be an `enum` (and rename `PaymentReceived` to `IsPaymentReceived` to it makes more sense)

Comment: Stephen if i changes to true and false it stopped working completely

Comment: Then is the property your binding the radio buttons a `bool`? You code makes no sense - what do you think all that code in your controller code is doing? - if the value is `true` then set it to `true`? And then your convert a `bool` to a `bool`?

Comment: Stephen i gave as like this                                                                                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.PaymentType, "true", new { id = "" }) Cash
           
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.PaymentType, "false", new { id = "" }) Cheque its working and i have one another doubt

Comment: What doubt? And your code should be `<label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.PaymentType, true, new { id = "" })<span>Cash</span></label>` and delete the `@Html.LabelFor(model => model.PaymentReceived)`

Comment: ok i will change and give me 2 mins it little bit big so i need time to type and post the question.